# Problem with net instantiation

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a very simple statemachine that sets some control signals to interact with a third party IP. The code looks roughly as follows:

```
entity testip is
  port (
  ...
    fifo_dataout        : in  std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
    ip_dataout          : in  std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
    ip_ce                 : out std_logic;
    ip_we                : out std_logic;
    ip_datain            : out std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
  );
end entity testip;

architecture imp of testip is

  signal ip_ce_ns     : std_logic;
  signal ip_we_ns     : std_logic;
  signal ip_ce_cs     : std_logic;
  signal ip_we_cs     : std_logic;
  signal ip_dataout_i : std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
  ...

  attribute keep: string;
  attribute keep of ip_ce    : signal is "True";
  attribute keep of ip_we    : signal is "True";

  begin

  COMB : process (...)
      begin
        ip_ce_ns          <= ip_ce_cs;
        ip_we_ns          <= ip_we_cs;

     case ip_nstate_cs is
        when IDLE      =>
        ...

     end case;
 end process COMB;

 REG: process (Clk) is
   begin
      if (Clk'event and Clk = '1') then
         if (Rst = '1') then
              ip_ce_cs                <= '1';
              ip_we_cs                <= '1';
              ...
         else          
              ip_ce_cs                <= ip_ce_ns;
              ip_we_cs                <= ip_we_ns;
              ...
         end if;
    end if;
 end process REG;

S0:     ip_ce                 <= ip_ce_cs;
S1:     ip_we                <= ip_we_cs;
S2:     ip_datain           <= fifo_dataout;
S3:     ip_dataout_i       <= Ip_dataout;

end architecture imp;
```

Sythesis works fine, however, when applying the following constraint file I get ERROR:ConstraintSystem:59 - NET "testip/ip_we" not found. The same occurs for testip/ip_datain and testip/ip_ce.

```
 Net testip/ip_datain<*> MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
 Net testip/ip_ce MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
 Net testip/ip_we MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
```

I checked the netlist, and indeed there is neither a testip/ip_we, a testip/ip_ce nor a testip/ip_datain net. Anyone an idea why the other nets are not in the netlist, all very confusing.

Many thanks for any feedback!

EDIT: Please see attached the detailed instantiation in the top module file:

```
icap0 : entity icap.hwicap
    generic map (pindex => 2, paddr => 2, pmask => 16#FFE#, C_SIMULATION => 2,
           C_FAMILY => "virtex5")
    port map (rst => rstn, clk => clkm, apbi => apbi, apbo => apbo(2));


Net icap0/icap_statemachine_I1/Icap_datain<*> MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
Net icap0/icap_statemachine_I1/Icap_ce MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
Net icap0/icap_statemachine_I1/Icap_we MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
```

This should do the job, but when looking at the netlist and looking for signals Icap_ce
or Icap_we they are just non-existent. I just think these nets are not there or have been renamed so that I cant find them anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The signals were probably optimized away...it looks like you have a wire loop generating ip_ce and you're driving ip_datain with the non-existant fifo_dataout.  You don't indicate what you're targeting, but modern FPGA synthesis are by default very aggressive at removing unused/undriven logic, typically with nothing more than an info or warning message in the log.  Crawl through your syntheses logs and look for anything odd related to the signals you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I checked the synthesis log and it does not say anywhere that the signals have been trimmed. In fact, those signals are not even mentioned at all... Quite confusing

Answer (score 1):

As Charles says, your signals are probably being optimized away.

If you set the synthesis attribute to *preserve hierarchy*, then your ports will be maintained (but you miss out on some optimizations).

I guess you aren't really as bothered about the signals as your are about the timing. In which case, use a start and end point, rather than a net name in your constraints.

Alternatively, you can set the *keep* attribute on the signals in the source code. That can of course make your source code less portable. My recommendation would be to use start and end points.

Is testip your top level? If not try

```
Net "*/testip/ip_ce" MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
```

is this net detected?

```
Net "*/testip/ip_ce_cs" MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
```

Actually, I've missed something more obvious, what is the name of the instance of testip? Use that instead of testip in your constraint. i.e.

```
u_test_ip : testip
```

then

```
Net "*/u_test_ip/ip_ce" MAXDELAY = 2 ns;
```

Comment: Cheers Georg, I will have a look at this keep attribute and the preserve hierarchy option. Could you please eleborate what you mean with "start and end" point, this is not 100% clear to me what you mean.

Comment: Hi Richard, tell me what tool are you using for synthesis and I'll write an example for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Georg, I am using XST 12.1 for sythesis. I am just trying my luck with the keep attribute, lets see if this works.

Comment: I added now the keep attribute as you can see above, unfortunately, it does not have any effect and ip_ce and ip_we cant be found in the netlist...

Comment: using Net "*/testip/ip_ce" MAXDELAY = 2 ns; instead gives me unfortuantely the same result.

Comment: Can you share some more details about the design. Namely how is ip_ce connected at the higher level?

Comment: To make things a bit easier the design can be download from here: http://www.4shared.com/file/lU5hYRJ2/hwicap.html You can see in HWicap.vhd how the signals from the statemachine are connected. Many thanks

Comment: That doesn't include your testip file or top level.

Comment: Sorry for that George, please see in the edits of my original post how I instantiate the module and how the constraints are applied in full.

Comment: Have you tried used the constraints editor in the ISE GUI. By browsing the hierarchy for your signals, you'll get a better idea of how they are named.

Comment: I used the Planahead to have a look at the nextlist, and unfortuantely these signals are just not there :(

Comment: I still can't see how you are instantiating your testip entity. Are you seeing any testip nets in Planahead?

Comment: Yes, I can see some nets in Planhead that come from my statemachine. For example, "icap0/icap_statemachine_I1/Send_done_cs" is one of them, however there are no "icap0/icap_statemachine_I1/Icap_ce"...

Answer (score 1):

I think the `keep` attribute is case-sensitive, have you tried `"true"` rather than `"True"`?